# Convert Javascript function to python

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a function which takes values from two classes and maps it into an array. The array then gets pushed into a send email function.

```
    var p1 = document.getElementsByClassName('emailtest'),
        email = [].map.call(p1, function(email) {
            return email.value;
        }).join(',');

    var p2 = document.getElementsByClassName('reciptest'),
        rname = [].map.call(p2, function(rname) {
            return rname.value;
        }).join(',');

var to = [];
    var p3 = email.split(',');
    var p4 = rname.split(',');

    p3.forEach(function(em, i) {
        var recipient = {
            email: em,
            name: null,
            type: 'to'
        };
        if (p4.length > i)
            recipient = p4[i];

        to.push(recipient);
    });
```

How would I implement this in python and more specifically django ? I have a rough idea on splitting the strings but am not sure how to convert the last section p3.forEach(function(em, i) and to.push(recipient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
to = []
p3 = email.split(',')
p4 = rname.split(',')
for i,em in enumerate(p3):
    recipient = {'email': em, 'name': None, 'type': to}
    if len(p4) > i:
        recipient = p4[i]
    to.append(recipient)
```

Comment: Hey thanks. In regards to the string split. Would it be best to use request.POST.getlist ?

Comment: Only if the POST data has already been split for you.  If it comes in as a single comma-delimited string, then no, you have to split it yourself.

Comment: GET is probably the easiest

Comment: Ok . This is actually a part of a broader issue that Im trying to solve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329834/append-multiple-recipient-email-and-name-into-emailmultialternatives   Would really appreciate some advice on this